# Algorithm to find the minimum required transactions to settle an expense?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, expense-splitting

So I have a json object of the following sort:

```
{ 
  Alice: 184, 
  Bob: 99, 
  Charlie: -286
}
```

where key is the name of the person and value is the amount they are owed/owe. positive indicates owed, negative indicates owes.

I want to create/find an algorithm that gives the minimum (if not minimum then pretty efficient atleast) required transactions to balance the settlement to 0. In this case,

```
Expexted Output:
Charlie owes Alice 184. Charlie owes Bob 99.
```

Obviously it wont always be this simple. I tried looking at other similar answers but it became too complex for me to understand. can someone please explain a simpler way to achieve this.

I thought of separating into 2 objects, for debitors and creditors and arranging them in ascending and descending order, but didnt know how to proceed then.

Comment: It's closely related to the subset sum problem I think. So unless you want just a good solution but not the best it will be pretty difficult.

Comment: As @maraca said, it is a subset sum problem, and it's a known NP-hard problem. If the constraints are small you can solve this using dynamic programming with a time complexity of ```O(abs(amount_owed) * total_no_of_people)```.

Comment: @sharpnife  I would think the complexity would even be higher than that if multiple people owed money.

Comment: It's an interesting question, I'm assuming there will be multiple people owed/owe.,   You might even find to make the least number of transactions the owes might pay owes before owed.  So sorting etc, might not really help.  Due to PC's been so fast these days, problems like this can often be done using brute force (random), and then use a max allowed time to find solution, while keeping a tally of the best solution.  As long as the list is not in the 1000's, you would likely find this could be completed in fractions of a second with a very optimal solution.

Comment: Another idea that should pretty much keep transaction down, make one of your owed collect all money from the other owed, and then this 1 person pays everybody else.. :)

Comment: Another constraint you probably need is that people owing money can never receive money and people waiting for money can never pay money. Otherwise you can get ugly results.

Comment: I made my own implementation based on my needs, the code for which can be found:
https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3z3a5ybgz
Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but seems to be working. decimal error at the end is because of js floating point error.